# Golang API Server won't receive Swagger API calls

Tags: go, swagger, mux

My basic golang API server, created using mux package, is causing me some issues.
I'm trying to use a provided SwaggerUI to commit calls to my localHost (at port 8080), and it doesn't seem to reach my server.
At the same time, using the same Curl command through Postman desktop-app, I'm able to reach and communicate with the server.
I've tried adding CORS support to my server and use different swagger-allowing golang commands, but nothing works (with/without the CORS code).

I'm not sure whether the issue is with my firewall/antiVirus, although even when I turn both off, I can seem to reach my server using the SwaggerUI tool.

Any ideas/tips on how to address the issue?

```
server := mux.NewRouter()
server.HandleFunc("/api/people/", addPerson).Methods("POST")

headersOk := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Accept", "X-Requested-With"})
originsOk := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{os.Getenv("ORIGIN_ALLOWED")})
methodsOk := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "DELETE", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH"})
http.Handle("/", server)

log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", handlers.CORS(originsOk, headersOk, methodsOk)(server)))
```

Comment: So did you set ORIGIN_ALLOWED to anything? Like `*`

Comment: Yes, I've also tried to remove the os.Getenv("ORIGIN_ALLOWED") and just leave it with * instead. Both didn't work for me